# How can I refer to the Winter Bash event in a shorter and more descriptive way?

Tags: adjectives

I am writing an essay about *[Winter Bash](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/)*, and I want to find a shorter way to say that Winter Bash is an event that **repeats annually during Winters**.

I have already thought about several ways to call this event, but I think they are not good.

- Temporary event (It does not show reoccurrence)
- Seasonal event (It seems as if the Winter Bash is reoccurring every season, but it only happens in Winter)
- Annual event (It again may cause confusion)

Do you have any suggestions to help me shorten and convey my message (bolded above) in a better way? What do you think about my own thoughts?

===
I know I can always just say Winter Bash, but I look for a way to generalize and indicate the nature of the event in a more descriptive manner.

Comment: Seasonal is fine. There are events that are not temporary? Annual events cause confusion? Winter bashes occur in warm weather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***brumal***: 'indicative of or occurring in the winter' [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brumal)

*No subject has more engaged the naturalist in all ages than the **brumal** retreat of the swallow.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Treasury_of_Knowledge_and_Library_Re/EjY-AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22brumal%20retreat%22&pg=PA437&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22brumal%20retreat%22)

*The wind was whipping the snow into a flurry fury, bruiting the eddies about like **brumal** rumors.* (Joan Connor, 'The Folly of Being Comforted'. TriQuarterly,  Fall, Iss. 123; pg. 169, 2005)

Examples from the OED (which defines it as 'ff, belonging to, or characteristic of winter; wintry'):

> 1813  *Belfast Monthly Mag.* 31 Jan. 47/1        
> *Dark indeed are the **brumal** days that have no sun shine.*
> 1870  J. R. Lowell *My Study Windows* 32        
> *What cheerfulness there was in **brumal** verse was that of Horace's.*
> 1934  E. Linklater *Magnus Merriman* vii. 84        
> *That **brumal** solitude derived from knowledge of hunger in December and thrashing gales in March.*
> 1983  M. O'Donoghue *Jedder's Land* (1984) 41        
> *Clumps of snowdrops..had magically withstood the **brumal** cold of the past week.*
> 2001  P. Ball *Bright Earth* viii. 205        
> *Here is a very different kind of atmospheric lighting: cold and **brumal**, veiled in the shadows of a low sun.*

Comment: I've never heard it before, but a great word!